# Visual Studio 2010 - Wild window appeared?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, window

I pressed some buttons and suddenly this wild dropdown appeared:

[image]

It's at the top of the editing screen and I'd like to hide it again as it messes up my screen space. I only run ReSharper and I already looked at the settings there and in Visual Studio but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go `Tools` > `Options`, `Text Editor` > `C#`, uncheck `Navigation bar`.

I have one of these, but it's only ~1 line of text tall, not ~3 lines like yours. I've no idea how that could have happened.

Comment: Thanks, when I disabled it and I noticed that I had something there but not this huge block. When I enabled it again it was 1 line again, not sure what happened but I'm happy again, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Is it the navigation bar?

If so, you can switch it off with this setting in Tools > Options.

[image: navigation bar]